# Dynamic allocation for arrays in MIPS

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

Our team is trying to create a compiler that's fed code and produces MIPS assembly from it.

To tackle array declaration at the global scope, we create a label for the array in .text and reserve 4 bytes to hold the address pointing to the start of the array in memory.

```
    .text
arr:    .space 4
    .data
...
li $t0, N         # (where N = number of elements in arr)
li $v0, 9         # Load system instruction to allocate dynamic memory
li $t1, 4         # 4 bytes per element
mult $t0, $t1     # Calculates how big the allocated memory has to be in bytes.
mflo $a0          # Loads this value into $a0
syscall           # Allocates memory and returns address into $v0
la $s0, arr       # load address of arr into $s0
sw $v0, ($s0)     # Save allocated memory address into the space reserved in .text
```

However, the last instruction doesn't seem to be working properly for us.

[This image](http://puu.sh/1BfLU) shows exactly where the error occurs and the state of the registers at that time. I'm unsure why it's causing an error.

Edit: some more information on the error produced, updated to encompass the modified instructions at the end

```
[00400000] 8fa40000  lw $4, 0($29)            ; 183: lw $a0 0($sp) # argc 
[00400004] 27a50004  addiu $5, $29, 4         ; 184: addiu $a1 $sp 4 # argv 
[00400008] 24a60004  addiu $6, $5, 4          ; 185: addiu $a2 $a1 4 # envp 
[0040000c] 00041080  sll $2, $4, 2            ; 186: sll $v0 $a0 2 
[00400010] 00c23021  addu $6, $6, $2          ; 187: addu $a2 $a2 $v0 
[00400014] 0c100009  jal 0x00400024 [main]    ; 188: jal main 
[00400018] 00000000  nop                      ; 189: nop 
[0040001c] 3402000a  ori $2, $0, 10           ; 191: li $v0 10 
[00400020] 0000000c  syscall                  ; 192: syscall # syscall 10 (exit) 
[00400024] 34080003  ori $8, $0, 3            ; 9: li $t0, 3 # Load immediate value into register $t0 
[00400028] 34020009  ori $2, $0, 9            ; 10: li $v0, 9 
[0040002c] 34090004  ori $9, $0, 4            ; 11: li $t1, 4 
[00400030] 01090018  mult $8, $9              ; 12: mult $t0, $t1 
[00400034] 00002012  mflo $4                  ; 13: mflo $a0 
[00400038] 0000000c  syscall                  ; 14: syscall 
[0040003c] 3c101001  lui $16, 4097 [arr0]     ; 15: la $s0, arr0 
[00400040] ae020000  sw $2, 0($16)            ; 16: sw $v0, ($s0)


PC       = 400040
EPC      = 40003c
Cause    = 1c
BadVAddr = 1004002f
Status   = 3000ff12
```

Answer (score 3):

The last instruction `sw $v0, arr0($0)` = `MEM[$0 + arr0] = $v0` which isn't correct. However you'll be given the amount of  memory requested and it is needed to save that memory pointer in a register until scope of program. The assignment might look like this,

```
arr:    .space 4

syscall             # Allocates memory and returns address into $v0
la     $s0, arr     # arr is pointer address
st     $v0, 0($s0)  # start base address of array
```

Now `arr` is base address of 4 bytes of memory holding the address of memory content. For good practice it is important to de-allocate the memory assigned back to OS as,

```
li      $v0,10      # return back to OS
syscall
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried out the code you suggested, but "st" doesn't seem to be a valid MIPS operation. http://www.mips.com/media/files/MD00565-2B-MIPS32-QRC-01.01.pdf

Comment: I tried using
    la $s0, arr
    sw $v0, $s0

but this doesn't seem to change anything. I've updated the question with more information.